# Convolution operator has norm 1 with respect to $L^2$ norm

Tags: normed-spaces, convolution

Let $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ be the following:

$$C_c = \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \mid \exists \text{ } T > 0 \text{ s.t. } f(t) = 0  \text{ for } |t| \geq T\}$$

Let $T_n \in L(C_c(\mathbb{R}))$ be a linear operator such that:

$$T_n u = \delta_n *u, \forall u \in C_c(\mathbb{R}),$$

where

$$
\delta_n(t)= \begin{cases} 
      n^2(t+1/n) & -1/n \leq t \leq 0 \\
      -n^2(t-1/n) & 0 < t \leq 1/n \\
      0 & \text{elsewhere} 
   \end{cases}
$$

I have to prove that with respect to the 2-norm, the operator $T_n$ has $\|T_n\| = 1$ and I have succeeded in proving that $\|T_nu\|_2 \leq \|u\|_2, \forall u \in C_c(\mathbb{R}).$

Now, I remained  to prove that $\exists \text{ } u \in C_c(\mathbb{R}) \text{ s.t. } \|T_nu\|_2 = \|u\|_2$, but I really don't get how $u$ should be shaped in order to satisfy it.

Comment: You don't have to prove that $\exists \text{ } u \in C_c(\mathbb{R}) \text{ s.t. } \|T_nu\|_2 = \|u\|_2$. You have to prove that it exists a sequence $(u_n)$ in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\Vert u_n \Vert_2 = 1$ such that $\lim \Vert T_n u_n \Vert_2 = 1$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net can you explain me the theory behind it? or give me any reference? And the last limit you wrote, the limit is just for $u_n$ I guess and not for $T_n$. Therefore it's like the $\lim_{m\to\infty} ||T_nu_m||_2$

Comment: You’re right. The limit is just for $u_m$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net any ideas on how this sequence can be?

Comment: See my hint below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probable solution:**

What we are interested in is proving that:

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \|T_nu_m\|_2 = 1$$

If we write $u_m(t) = a_mv_m(t) $, where $v_m(t)$ defined as the hint by @mathcounterexamples.net, we can substitute in the limit (for simplicity we use $\|T_nu_m\|_2^2$):

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \|T_nu_m\|_2^2 = \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\|T_nv_m\|_2^2, $$

where ${a_m}^2 = \frac{1}{\|v_m\|_2^2} = \frac{3m}{3m^2+2}$

Then, according to what @mathcounterexamples.net pointed out, the integral can be split as:

$$\|T_nv_m\|_2^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|(\delta_n*v_m)(t)|^2dt $$

$$ = \int_{-1/n-1/m}^{1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt + \int_{1/n}^{m-1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt + \int_{m-1/n}^{1/n+1/m+m}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt = \int_{-1/n-1/m}^{1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt + \int_{1/n}^{m-1/n}dt + \int_{m-1/n}^{1/n+1/m+m}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt $$

Plugging it back in the limit:

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\bigg(\int_{-1/n-1/m}^{1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt + \int_{1/n}^{m-1/n}dt + \int_{m-1/n}^{1/n+1/m+m}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt\bigg)$$

But in the first and in the third integral:

$$0 \leq (\delta_n*v_m)(t) \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq (\delta_n*v_m)^2(t) \leq 1$$

Therefore, for the first integral:

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\int_{-1/n-1/m}^{1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt \leq \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\bigg(\sup_{t \in [-1/n-1/m,1/n]}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)\bigg)^2(2/n+1/m) = \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2(2/n+1/m) = 0$$

And for the third integral as well:

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\int_{m-1/n}^{m+1/m+1/n}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)dt \leq \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\bigg(\sup_{t \in [m-1/n,m+1/m+1/n]}(\delta_n*v_m)^2(t)\bigg)^2(2/n+1/m) = \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2(2/n+1/m) = 0$$

Finally we are left with:

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2\bigg(\int_{1/n}^{m-1/n}dt\bigg) = \lim_{m\to\infty} {a_m}^2(m-2/n) = \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{3m}{3m^2+2}(m-2/n) = 1  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider the function

$$v_m(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x \le -\frac{1}{m}\\
1+mx& -\frac{1}{m} \le x \le 0\\
1 & 0\le x \le m\\
m^2-mx+1& m\le x \le m+\frac{1}{m}\\
0 & m+\frac{1}{m}
\end{cases}$$

And the function $u_m =a_m v_m $ with $a_m$ chosen such that $\Vert u_m \Vert_2=1$. You’ll be able to prove that

$$\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \Vert T_n u_m\Vert_2 =1.$$

Notice in particular that:
$$T_nv_m(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x \le -\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}\\
1 & \frac{1}{n} \le x \le m -\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & m+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} \le x
\end{cases}$$ and $0 \le T_nv_m(x) \le 1$ elsewhere.

For example for $\frac{1}{n} \le x \le m -\frac{1}{n}$:

$$T_nv_m(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-t)v_m(t) \ dt = \int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} \delta_n(x-t)v_m(t) \ dt = \int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} \delta_n(x-t)\ dt=1$$

Comment: But is this together with the first part where I proved that $||T_nu||_2 \leq ||u||_2$ or this alone is enough?

Comment: This is together with what your prove.

Comment: I tried to compute the Fourier transform first in order to check if, after the right coefficient $a_m$, what's the form of $\lim_{m\to\infty} ||T_nu_m||_2 = \lim_{m\to\infty} ||\mathfrak{F}(T_nu_m)||_2 = \lim_{m\to\infty} ||\mathfrak{F}(T_n)\mathfrak{F}(u_m)||_2$, but I got that $\mathfrak{F}(v_m)(iw) = (m/w^2)(e^{-iwm} - e^{-iw/m} - e^{-iw(m+1/m)})$. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think that you need to go through Fourier transform. I updated my answer to provide you with more details.

Comment: Actually, I think that you are not completely right. In fact, what you wrote is true for $n=1$, i.e., $T_1v_m$. Whereas, when $n \neq 1$, then $T_nv_m = (2n-1)/n^2$, for $1/n \leq x \leq m-1/n$

Comment: I edited with my computation. Can you show yours?

Comment: Basically I checked graphically computing the area under the trapezoidal figure, which is indeed the convolution (https://imgur.com/a/ox24RxF). You can think also about the fact that since $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \delta_n(t) dt = 1$, the convolution has to be lower than 1 since the function $\delta_n$ is not "completely included" under the area of $v_m(t)$. (if imgur is not working, try this https://ibb.co/k5DFDo).

Comment: You’re misleading what convolution is. It is based on a product, not a kind of intersection like your figure is showing. Use the definition and compute integrals! A product of a function $\delta$ with a constant function equal to $1$ is equal to $\delta$.

Comment: Aaaah now I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80694/discussion-between-giovanni-13-and-mathcounterexamples-net).